Debug Ansible MODULE FAILURE, without stdout or stderr
I'm running an ansible playbook the following way:

created a docker-image

FROM php:8.1.28-apache-bookworm

RUN apt install -y python3 \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python


started the container
Added it to my inventory

all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: docker
  hosts:
    test-container:


Ran the following task

    - name: Download limesurvey installation
      # debugger: on_failed
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: "https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/archive/refs/tags/{{ limesurvey_version }}.tar.gz"
        dest: "/tmp/limesurvey.tar.gz"
        mode: "755"

and I get the following error:
{
  "changed": false, 
  "module_stderr": "",
  "module_stdout": "",
  "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
  "rc": 0
}

I'm pretty sure, that this is a setup issue, but how can I debug this error?
UPDATE:

the task seems to work, but ansible complains
Adding ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 allows to run re-run the files locally, also adding debug statements. It didn't help, because running the files in the container just worked (see -vvv for the actual commands).
I edited the local get_url module and raised Exception till I pinned down the error to the following line.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/get_url.py#L432. That worked because I always found the specific error, except after the line in question


I cannot reproduce that behavior. Running with docker 27.2.1 and ansible 2.17.2.

Thanks for the effort. It's defintely a setup issue. I currenlty work in devcontainers. If I run the setup outside (mac m1), it work's just fine.

Are you mounting the /tmp folder from your host? What are the rights and ownership of the folder?

/tmp is not mounted. It only doesn't work within my devcontainer setup on an m1.
My main question is answered though (basically the Update part + you can "explode" the scripts on the remote machine, allowing to set break points). I try to elaborate in an answer later.

I couldn't solve my problem, but I learned how to debug and module-failure without any additional infos.

run the playbook with -vvvv
Adding ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 allows to run re-run the files locally
You can now run the files on the targeted machine (depending on task an setup e.g. /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxx/AnsibleZ_stat.py)
If you add explode as first argument you can also edit the module (normally embedded as a zip).
If you cannot easily access the remote machine, you can also edit the local module file. I raised exceptions to find my way round. On every run it's updated.

